# Add parameter to submit form laravel

Tags: laravel, url, submit

here you can see my form where I put in a username and have a hidden idgroup field.

```
{!! Form::open(array('route'=>'create.invitation')) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('username', 'Username')}}
        {{Form::text('username', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Username'])}}
        <input type="hidden" name="idgroup" value="{{$group}}"/>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{Form::submit('Submit',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-close" href="{{ route('home') }}">Cancel</a>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

After that this route leads me to my controller function

```
Route::post('invitation/show', 'InvitationController@create')->name('create.invitation');
```

How can I add the username and the idgroup to my url?
My problem is now when I click submit I get back this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/invitation/create and when I click enter to the url line I get an error no message because no parameter will pass to the function.

Add. Here is the function

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
     'username' => [
     'required', 'alpha_num', new ExistingUser, new UserNotAdmin
            ]
    ]);

    $username = $request->username;
    $iduser = User::where('name', $username)->select('id')->first();
    $group = $request->idgroup;

    return view('invitation.overview')->with('group', $group)->with('iduser', $iduser);
 }
```

Comment: add your function and whats the error here??

Comment: why not use route model binding and do something like this:  Route::post('invitation/show/{group}', 'InvitationController@create')->name('create.invitation');  then in your controller you can type hint and in the create function you could do seomthing like public function create(Request $request, Group $group) { }

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass parameter inside POST body without submitting a form.

But you can try to allow both GET or POST by using `any()` for the route, so you can test the page around.

```
Route::any('invitation/show', 'InvitationController@create')->name('create.invitation');
```

And then, you can try pass variable through queries inside URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/invitation/create?username=something&idgroup=1
```